# C# Wcf POST values

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to receive a POST request send by a html form.

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "post_test")]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "post",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result postMth(Stream stream);


    public Result postMth(Stream stream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        NameValueCollection post = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data);
        throw new Exception("Value = " + post["mypost"]);
    }
```

How can i receive my POST var send by my form ?

data result:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary24UETQYkoz77p3Tt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mypost"

some text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code in your `postMth`:

```
MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(stream);
if (parser.Success)
{
    // Put your code here
}
```

**MultipartParser** library is a simple class that parses mutipart form data that contains binary data and returns a file stream.

> [MultipartParser @ CodePlex](http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't want to save the content. I just want to get my POST